# Derivative $\frac{dt}{dx}$ using $\frac{dx}{dt}$

Tags: derivatives

Suppose I have a function $x(t)$ such that $\frac{d}{dt}x=x(t)y(t)$. Can I affirm hat
$$\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dt}}=\frac{1}{x(t)y(t)}$$
I am sorry but I am a bit confused about this argument

Comment: The function $x$ has to be invertible and, both the function and its inverse has to be differentiable, and also the derivative can not be $0$.

Comment: Assuming the hypotheses specified by QED are satisfied, you can start with $x(t)$ and its inverse function $t(x)$. By definition you have $t(x(\tau)) = \tau$. Now differentiate both sides with respect to $\tau$.

Answer (score 2):

When both are defined you have $$\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dt}}=\frac{1}{x(t)y(t)}.$$

Answer (score 2):

You are combining two issues in one.

1. for a differentiable function with nonzero derivative, it is true that $$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=\dfrac1{\dfrac{dt}{dx}}$$ by differential calculus.
2. if $f(t)=x(t)\,y(t)\ne0$, then $\dfrac1{f(t)}=\dfrac1{x(t)\,y(t)}.$ This is elementary arithmetic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question was about the first issue. Therefore I can prove that using the limit of the difference quotient?

Comment: @user268193: a proof can be based on the identity $$\frac {x(t+h)-x(t)}h=\frac k{t(x+k)-t(x)}$$ where $x(t+h)=x(t)+k$.